# My event procedure does nothing when I click it

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having two issues with my VBA in Access the first one is when I click the Search button nothing happens and the second one is states that theres a error with the ME Clause.

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

  Dim strWhere As String, lngLen As Long
  Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
  strWhere = ""

  If Not IsNull(Me.AssignedTo) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([AssignedTo] Like '*" & Me.AssignedTo & "*') AND"  
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.OpenedBy) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([OpenedBy] Like '*" & Me.OpenedBy & "*') AND"  
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.Status) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Status] Like '*" & Me.Status & "*')AND"  
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.Category) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Category] Like '*" & Me.Category & "*')AND"  
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.Priority) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Priority] Like '*" & Me.Priority & "*')AND"
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.OpenedDateFrom) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([EnteredOn] >= " & Format(Me.OpenedDateFrom, conJetDate) & ") AND "  
  End If

  If Not IsNull(Me.DueDateFrom) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([EnteredOn] <= " & Format(Me.DueDateFrom, conJetDate) & ") AND "  
  End If

  lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5

  If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
  Else

  End If

  strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
  Me.Filter = strWhere
  Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am confused. If nothing happens when Search  is clicked, how do you know anything about the second problem? BTB, you should ask only one question at a time,Try testing either by debugging or using MsgBox, eg. MsgBox(Me.Status)

Comment: Because I created a macro and ran it and the debug issues came up.

Comment: Do you know why the event procedure isn't doing anything?

Comment: If you do not absolutely need a macro, creating an event procedure instead of a macro should solve your problems.

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` set?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you have to `Me.Requery` or `Me.Refresh` after you set `Me.Filter`. Also, for your dates, you have to surround them with the `#`.   I do believe you need to use 4 instead of 5 to remove the extra `AND`.  Lastly, I changed your delimiter on the strings to `"`.  That is just my personal preference. See Code:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
  Dim strWhere As String
  strWhere = IIF(Len(Me.AssignedTo & "") <> 0, "([AssignedTo] Like ""*" & Me.AssignedTo & "*"") AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.OpenedBy & "") <> 0, "([OpenedBy] Like ""*" & Me.OpenedBy & "*"") AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.Status & "") <> 0, "([Status] Like ""*" & Me.Status & "*"") AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.Category & "") <> 0, "([Category] Like ""*" & Me.Category & "*"") AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.Priority & "") <> 0, "([Priority] Like ""*" & Me.Priority & "*"") AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.OpenedDateFrom & "") <> 0, "([EnteredOn] >= #" & Format(Me.OpenedDateFrom, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#) AND", "") & _
             IIF(Len(Me.DueDateFrom & "") <> 0, "([EnteredOn] <= #" & Format(Me.DueDateFrom, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#) AND", "") 

  If Len(strWhere & "") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
  Else
    Me.Filter = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere & "") - 4)
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.Requery
  End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Linger, when I dropped in your code and click search the event hasn't triggered.

Comment: **@user3666237**, I modified the code.  Try my update and see if it works for you.  Also, you may want to look at [**Requery vs Refresh**](http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/requery-v-refresh/) to see witch one you really need.

Comment: Nothing is happening when I click the search button.  Do you know why?

Comment: @LInder thanks I realized that the code works but for some reason the table in my form doesn't respond to vba command filters.  Where in my code refer to the table I'm trying to filter within the form.

Comment: **@user3666237**, I am guessing you have the **Record Source** property set to the table you want the form to use.  Applying a filter changes the data shown based on the **Record Source** you have set on the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not absolutely need a macro, creating an event procedure instead of a macro should solve your problems. A simple way to create an event procedure for a button is to right-click on the button in Design View and then click Build Event. You can then copy and paste the code from the Macro into the Event Procedure and delete the macro.